# make __call__ a specific interface in Base class available for all derive class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Base class with a public `fn` in it. I want to make all classes in the hierarchy system callable, and their `__call__`  actually translate their work to `fn`, the semantic is similar to `Class.__call__ = fn`. The following codes show how i currently implement.

```
class Base:
    def fn(self, *input):
        # ...

    __call__ = fn

class Derived(Base):
    def fn(self, input):
        # ...

    __call__ = fn
```

i know there is a kind of design that only define a `__call__` in the Base class, and in `__call__`'s function body, to translate its work to `fn`, each Derived class implement its own `fn`. The semantic is like "inherit a public interface and implement from Base, and in this public interface, each Derived class define its own version of implementation".

However, some of the `fn` have different parameter list, not always the same as the Base one, like the case that i show above. The above code can work, but i guess there must be better solutions, without the repeat definition in all classes of the hierarchy system.

So is there anyway to specific the `__call__` only one time in the Base class, but make it available for all Derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Python version >= 3.6, you could write an [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method of the `Base` class that assigns the `__call__` attribute of the child class to be equal to its `fn` attribute:

```
class Base:
    def fn(self, *args):
        return args
    __call__ = fn
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.__call__ = cls.fn

class Derived(Base):
    def fn(self, arg):
        print("In derived")
        return arg


Base()(1, 2, 3)
# (1, 2, 3)

Derived()(1)
# In derived
# 1
```

If you're using an older version of Python, you can accomplish a similar effect with a metaclass.

```
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__call__ = cls.fn

class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    def fn(self, *args):
        return args

class Derived(Base):
    def fn(self, arg):
        print("In derived")
        return arg
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided there is no need to use `__call__`. There is already a perfectly good mechanism, since python will call the class constructor. So simply `def __init__(self, *args):` and have that code call `fn` as appropriate.

You mention different parameter lists, without describing how to distinguish them. If it is a simple criterion, like `len(args)`, then what you have suffices. If it is more complex, you might want to put `**kwargs` in the signature, and have each method pick out just the keyword arguments that it recognizes.

Comment: Maybe i did not explain my question clearly. The example i provided above simplify the real situation. The point is, i want semantic like  ```__call__ == fn``` in the whole hierarchy system, without the repeat definition in all classes(no matter definition in the class definition or a instance attribute setting in the ```__init__```, the above code can work, but i guess there must be some better solutions in python world?